# Repeating texture by the .repeat prop but it stretches and distorts the texture in React Three Fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to give a .repeat value on my texture to repeat it more than 1 time, but it distorts (stretches at some points) after the process. wrapS and wrapT values are set to THREE.RepeatWrapping too, but speaking by the resulting texture, it feels like my wrapS and wrapT values are not working. Can someone see my minimal reproduction? Here is the codesandbox i prepared:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cannon-2s8vxp?file=/src/index.js

in the useEffect, i'm setting the necessary repeat values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just missing adding `texture.needsUpdate = true;`